# how to search by some of the characters in each cell not the whole word

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is a script file (JavaScript) I had loaded from the internet. it use with another HTML file to search data in google sheet. I have done all process and can run a web apps to search the data.

but it has only one problem that when searching you have to put a "full character" in any cell then it will show the data. for instance, if in the cell have "123456" in the search input you have to type "123456" only then it will show the data but if you type only "123" or "2345" the search will not match with this cell.

how could I change this script so that when I search can type only some character no need to type the full character in the cell an it still show that data. if "123456" in a cell but can type only "123" or "456" and it still match with this cell.

Thank you very much.

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}


/* PROCESS FORM */
function processForm(formObject){  
  var result = "";
  if(formObject.searchtext){//Execute if form passes search text
      result = search(formObject.searchtext);
  }
  return result;
}

//SEARCH FOR MATCHED CONTENTS 
function search(searchtext){
  var spreadsheetId   = '1q5TzCH_om_J8nX47XPUrJIyCBo5TZnYa5lCqsBGhGx8'; //** CHANGE !!!
  var dataRage        = 'A2:J126';                                    //** CHANGE !!!
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRage).values;
  var ar = [];
  
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
  return ar;
}
```

Comment: Please post code as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

- `data` is a 2-D value range (containing multiple rows and columns)
- If you want to check the content of every cell, you need to do with a nested loop

Sample:

```
...
data.forEach(function(row) {
  row.forEach(function(cell) {
    if (~cell.indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push(cell);
    }
  })
});
...
```

This will check if the search text is contained in the cell.

- If you want to do the opposite - check if the cell content is contained in the search text, you need to modify

`if (~cell.indexOf(searchtext))`

to

`if (~searchtext.indexOf(cell))`

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me try your script hope it work. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I try you code and it work. thank you very much. but it show only a cell that contain a keyword. may I ask how to show the whole row where the key word is contain not just the cell.

thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchtext.toString().toLowerCase())) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
  return ar;
}
```